# Python MIMEText adds (random?) unwanted new lines to message

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime, mime-message

I am just learning to send automated mails using the `smtplib` package and the `MIMEText` function from `email.mime.text`.

Everything seems to work fine, but sometimes (not always!) I find unwanted new lines in the mails I send. An example of the mails I receive:

> Hi Stefan,
>
> Your automated search obtained the following cheap listings per release stored in you Discogs application:
>
> No cheap listings found for 13669663
>
> :  'Alloy Mental - I am'..  **<----- Somehow this and previous line are cut in half..**

Those two lines should look like one line as in: *No cheap listings found for 13669663:  'Alloy Mental - I am'..*

I am not sure why this happens, in a few cases this does not happen (with other values for `release_id` and `full_title`, though I have not noticed a pattern there yet..)

My code looks as follows:

```py
import stmplib
import ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from logger import loguru

host = 'smtp.office365.com'
port = 587

def message_string(release_id, full_title):
    release_title = f"{release_id}: '{full_title}'"
    message = f"""\
Hi Stefan,

Your automated search obtained the following cheap listings per release stored in you Discogs application:
No cheap listings found for {release_title}..
"""
    return message


def create_message(release_id, full_title):
    message = message_string(release_id, full_title)
    msg = MIMEText(message.encode('utf-8'), _charset='utf-8')
    msg["Subject"] = "Daily Discogs tracking results"
    msg["From"] = "xxx"
    msg["To"] = "yyy"
    return msg


def send_message(release_id, full_title):
    msg = create_message(release_id, full_title)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(host=host, port=port) as server:
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(user="xxx", password="zzz")
        server.sendmail(from_addr="xxx", to_addrs="yyy", msg=msg.as_string())
        logger.info("email send, quitting server..")
        server.quit()
```

When I run the `message_string` function, the created string seems to be fine. But somewhere in the `MIMEText` part or the `send_message` part it breaks these strings in half. Can someone help me understand how and why that happens?

This happened for one of the mails I send:

Input

```py
msg = create_message(...)
print(msg.as_string())
```

Output

```py
'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nSubject: Daily Discogs tracking results\nFrom: xxx\nTo: yyy\n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\n'
```

EDIT: Swtiched to `email.message`'s `EmailMessage()`, now I obtain the following `msg.as_string()` result when printed:

```py
'Subject: Daily Discogs tracking results\nFrom: xxx\nTo: yyy\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\nHi Stefan,\n\nYour automated search obtained the following cheap listings per release store=\nd in you Discogs application:\nNo cheap listings found for 13669663: \'Rikhter - RIK1\'..\n\nNo cheap listings found for 1418651: \'Alloy Mental - I Am\'..\n\nNo cheap listings found for 13768683: \'DJ Gigola, Kev Koko - Tender Trance\'..\n\n=20\n1 listings found for 15367544: \'Paul Kalkbrenner - Speak Up EP\':\n++ BEST (< =E2=82=AC49.99):\nNo good listings found..\n\n+ GOOD (< =E2=82=AC62.99):\n- 1353902209: =E2=82=AC62.95 + =E2=82=AC7.5 shipping. See (http://www.discogs=\n.com//sell/item/1353902209)\n\n\nNo cheap listings found for 7346108: \'Paul Kalkbrenner - 7\'..\n\nNo cheap listings found for 99507: \'Aquila - Ritual EP\'..\n\n\nThank you,\nYour automated Discogs Listing Tracker\n   =20\n'
```

When I inspect my email in Outlook in the Firefox browser, I see an extra <br> has been added like:

```html
...
   <div class='PlainText'>
      Hi Stefan,
      <br>
      <br>
      Your automated search obtained the following cheap listings per release stored in you Discogs application:
      <br>
      No cheap listings found for 1418651
      <br>
      : 'Alloy Mental - I Am'..
      <br>
      <br>
      ....
   </div>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] to show the output of `print(msg.as_string())` prior to sending it, or actually then not send it at all?

Comment: As an aside, you should probably ditch this legacy code and use the Python 3.6+ `EmailMessage` API instead.

Comment: @tripleee I added the output of one of the mails I send out before, where the wrong spacing happened. I will read into `EmailMessage`, just do be sure you are referring to https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html ?

Comment: That's the one, yes; the first few paragraphs explain the difference. But probably start with tte simple [code examples in the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: The quotes around the result look suspicious, but do not as such explain the symptom you are getting. My vague guess is that you are transmitting overlong lines which are getting wrapped in transit, but that alone doesn't explain the problem, either. Could you show the source of the message you received, too? Anyhow, replacing the problematic code with a modern replacement might well resolve the issue.

Comment: By the by, your keyboard seems to be broken; there are two full stops in many places where we would normally expect one, both in your question and in the generated message.

Comment: @tripleee I changed my code to implement `EmailMessage()`, will edit post in a minute. The `msg.as_string()` shows some interesting behaviour, but I cannot exactly pinpoint what is the problem; it seems to be the `/'` combination..

Comment: @tripleee `/'` is not it. What do you mean with source of message?

Comment: The email you received; your question only shows how your email client rendered it, but the actual message looks something like the `msg.as_string()` output. Many email clients have something like "view source" to show that, just like many browsers let you inspect the raw HTML source of a web page. (Outlook in particular is even more idiotic than many other email clients; if you are an Outlook victim, maybe sned another message to a place like Gmail where you don't have to use Outlook.)

Comment: @tripleee, check my latest edit, an extra `<br>` is somehow entered into the message...

Comment: There is no `<br>` anywhere here, and the message is not HTML, so that particular string would simply render as the four literal characters `<`, `b`, `r`, `>`.

Comment: The browers's source shows how Outlook rendered the message into HTML, but we need to see the actual email source (which contains things like the `Content-type:` header etc)

Comment: Sounds like ultimately a pure Outlook problem, which only reinforces the recommendation to avoid that particular email client.

Comment: @tripleee okay, I will try to switch to a Gmail client and let you know if anything has changed. Many thanks for your patience and help, it is much appreciated!!